# Array in a POST form

Tags: php, html, arrays, forms, email

I want to save many "emails directions" in a input text array, and i want them to be related with a checkbox array called "subscribed" so i make:

```
<input type="email" name="email[]">
<input type="checkbox" name="emailsub[]" value="1"/>
```

If i try to print them, giving values:

```
one@one.com checked
two@two.com unchecked
three@three.com checked
```

with:

```
$emails = $_POST["email"];
    for ($i = 0, $limit = count($emails); $i < $limit; $i++){
        echo "Email: " . $_POST["email"][$i] . "<br />";
        echo "Sub: " . $_POST["emailsub"][$i] . "<br />";
    }
```

It gives me this result:

```
Email: one@one.com
Sub: 1
Email: two@two.com
Sub: 
Email: three@three.com
Sub: 
Email: 1
Sub:
```

What im doing wrong?

Thank you very much
Esteban

Comment: your `$_POST['email']`is an array. I sugest you to use foreach for this.

Comment: I think the problem is that when the checkbox for emailsub is left unchecked, PHP won't create an entry in the array for that checkbox, leaving the two arrays out of sync.

Comment: Now i done it with a foreach:
    foreach($_POST["email"] as $i => $array)
And it gives me the same result.

Comment: I think thats the problem too, Splashdust, but i cant find the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a logical error.
There is no correlation with `$_POST['emailsub']` and `$_POST['email']`.

If you don't check any `emailsub[]` input checkbox, then the `$_POST['emailsub']` array is empty.

If you check only the last input, then the `$_POST['emailsub']` array has only one element with key `0` (not `2`).

You should insert the index inside the html:

```
<input type="email" name="email[0]">
<input type="checkbox" name="emailsub[0]" value="1"/>
<input type="email" name="email[1]">
<input type="checkbox" name="emailsub[1]" value="1"/>
<!-- and so on.. -->
```

and PHP

```
$emails = $_POST['email'];
$checks = $_POST['emailsub'];

foreach($emails as $k=>$email) {
    echo "$email " . (isset($checks[$k])? " checked" : "unchecked");
}
```

Comment: Or, which might be easier to read in your server-side script: `email[0][address]` and `email[0][sub]` etc. Which can be read with: `$_POST[email][0][address]` and `$_POST[email][0][sub]`.

Comment: @giorgio yes. It could be a valid approach :)